# Is there a good solution for space efficiently showing multiple images in pylab/matplotlib?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am looking for a [montage.m](http://mirone.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.5.2/utils/montage.m) equivalent.
It takes some images and displays them in a nice and space-efficient manner.

I am mainly looking for something that is more space-efficient than subplots and can manage various colormaps.
So it doesn't need to be as comprehensive as in the link but before I start porting...

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#imagegrid might be useful

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for.
Why not as an answer?

Comment: because your description and what I think imagegrid does do not match.  I assumed that you want something that will deal with correctly sizing the images with respect to each, packing different aspect ratios etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into [imagegrid](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#imagegrid).

edit: this is very easily made into something usable

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10
images = [im for i in range(20)]

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 10),
                 axes_pad=0,
)

for i in range(20):
    grid[i].imshow(images[i], cmap=plt.get_cmap('Greys_r'))  # The AxesGrid object work as a list of axes.
    grid[i].axis('off')
plt.show(block=True)
```